# How to describe string with only repeated characters groups in regular expression in Python

Tags: python, regex

i.e. `'aaeegggwwqqqqq', 'ttteeyyjjj'`

I tried `r'(([a-z])\1*)+$'`, but get error said: cannot refer to open group.

Anyone can help me figure it out? Thanks!

Comment: You should be using: `r'(([a-z])\2*)+$'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does

```
(([a-z])\2*)+$
```

work?

Just quickly looking, `(([a-z])\2*)` is the first group and `([a-z])` is the second group. It looks like you meant to reference the second group.

Comment: Oh! yeah. Thanks user6917168!

Comment: But it seems to match anything...... Like 'fdsadf'... No idea what's the correct one

Comment: You probably want `{2,}`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374(v=vs.110).aspx.
Or try the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a non-capturing outer group:

```
re.match(r'(?:([a-z])\1+)+$', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f186ye/1)

This way, you do not have to re-adjust the backreferences inside the pattern.

An alternative is to use a named capture group and a named backreference:

```
re.match(r'((?P<l>[a-z])(?P=l)+)+$', s)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f186ye/2)

Here, `(?P<l>[a-z])` captures an ASCII lowercase letter into Group "l" and `(?P=l)+` matches 1 or more (`+` matches one or more occurrences of the quantified subpattern as many times as possible) ocurrences of the captured letter.

[Python demo](http://ideone.com/ipIFkx):

```
import re
s = ["aaeegggwwqqqqq", "ttteeyyjjj", "sdfghj"]
for x in s:
    if re.match(r'(?:([a-z])\1+)+$', x):
        print("{0} matches the pattern".format(x))
```

Output:

```
aaeegggwwqqqqq matches the pattern
ttteeyyjjj matches the pattern
```